# How to distinguish two instances of a class

Tags: java, constructor

I have two constructors of a class `Transactions` where they differ in the last argument where the first constructor takes a `Label` object and the second a `Box` object.

```
public class Transactions {
    private String date;
    private String kind;
    private int employee;
    private Label label;
    private Box box;

public Transactions(String date, String kind, int employee, Box box) {
    this.date = date;
    this.kind = kind;
    this.employee = employee;
    this.box = box;
}

public Transactions(String date, String kind, int employee, Label label) {
    this.date = date;
    this.kind = kind;
    this.employee = employee;
    this.label = label;
}


 ...

}
```

Lets say I have created an object of class `Transactions` which is `tr`.
How can I distinguish which one is it? The one with the `Label` object or the one with the `Box` object? Which constructor has been called?

Comment: It doesn't matter which constructor has been called but you can check whether `box` or `label` are null. Whether that's to be considered good design is a different matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to distinguish that, both objects probably should not be of the same class.

In your example, both classes could share a common superclass, or they should have a field of a special type, holding the common information.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check which one has just been called by checking if `this.label == null`.

You can also add a flag which would point which constructor has been called.

Anyway. If you are facing such a problem, you should definitely think out your code again. Those constructors probably shouldn't construct objects of the same class. Maybe some inheritance, maybe some composition...